# Borel Measurability of a function with countable discontinuity points.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f : X → \mathbb{R}$ such that the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous is countable. Prove that $f$ is Borel measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $a\in\mathbb R$, $$\{x | f(x)>a \} = \{x | f(x)>a \text{ and  } f(x) \text{ is continuous at } x \} \cup \{ x | f(x) >a \text{ and  } f(x) \text{ is discontinuous at } x \}$$ The former in the decomposition is open and the latter is countable (possibly finite), so they are both Borel measurable.

**Edit**: The above solution is false, for example [this famous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) is continuous at only irrational numbers, hence the first set in the above decomposition cannot be open, as there is no way for an open set not to include any rational numbers.

The right way is note that $X_0=\{x\mid f \text{ is continuous at } x\} = X\setminus\{x_1, x_2, \cdots\}$ is measurable, as $X$ is measurable and any countable set is also measurable. And we have $f|_{X_0}$ is measurable, since it's continuous, or more precisely $f|_{X_0}^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is the intersection of an open subset of $\mathbb R$ with $X_0$, hence measurable.
This shows the first subset in the above decomposition is measurable.

Comment: Please read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: This answer is wrong. The first set need not be open.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out! I made an correction, and hopefully it's correct now.

Comment: Actually, this answer looks fine for me. Since the question implicitly asks us to prove $f$ is measurable with respect to $X \cap \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, the first set is open in $X$ (not in $\mathbb R$).