# regarding measurability of functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

in this question [Borel Measurability of a function with countable discontinuity points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272439/borel-measurability-of-a-function-with-countable-discontinuity-points) $X$ is a Borel set , but I have $2$ questions   $1)$ if $X$ is every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ I think the theorem is also valid we only used preimage of open set is an open set  and countability so I don't see the point of being Borel .
$2)$ And I also think that the function also Lebesgue measurable since borel sigma algebra is contained in lebesgue sigma algebra , so open set are also measurable in lebesgue sigma algebra .
Are my statements correct?

Comment: The answer to the question in your link is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For $f$ being Borel Measurable, $X$ must be a Borel set. Indeed, take a (Lebesgue) measurable set $N$ set that is not a Borel set. Then, $f:N\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=1$ is continuous, However, $f^{-1}(\{1\})=N$ which is not Borel, and thus, $f$ is not Borel measurable.
- Indeed, if $f$ is Borel measurable, then it's Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , instead for $f$ being Lebesgue Measurable is true that $X$ could be any subset of $\mathbb{R} ?$

Comment: and another question ,sorry if I am bothering you your example is correct and you are completely right . In the link the guy says the first set is open , but it is open even if I change the set X with another set not borel will still be open  and so i will arrive to the same conclusion , that is my problem . What is the missing point here ?

Comment: For your first question, yes as far as $X$ is Lebesgue measurable. For your second question, since the Borel $\sigma -$algebra is generated by open sets, open sets are Borel sets, so no chance to find an open set that is not a Borel set... @Dsrksidemath